# Pyinstaller outputs big files. What is the best way to distribute to other people?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I packaged my python code into .exe file through pyinstaller. Because I have pandas as a library, the output file was big - 500M+. However, my company is not allowed to have .exe file on SharePoint and I certainly cannot zip the 500M file and send it to other people. Is there any way to work around it?

I have used virtualenv to limit the libraries packaged into the file: just pandas, numpy and openpyxl

Thank you!!

Comment: If your company does not want ``.exe`` on SharePoint, I doubt they will want you to send around executable scripts via email, either.  Have you checked with your IT department?

Comment: no, .exe cannot be shared with email. I am checking with IT now but just wondering if other people have similar problems and if there are any creative approaches to solve that.

Comment: Have you considered using [UPX](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-upx)?